# xampp's mysql connectivity issue

Tags: mysql, jdbc, xampp, odbc, connectivity

I am trying to connect my eclipse with xampp's mysql but its not even able to ping mysql. I already added the connector in classpath and also modified the my.ini(config of xampp's mysql) by uncommenting bindaddress="127.0.0.1" I tried with various url to establish jdbc connectivity like "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/login", "root", ""
"http://localhost:3306/login", "root", ""

Please help any suggestion will be welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Java to a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

JDBC connection URLs begin with `jdbc:`, not `http:`. The basic form is

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
```

where `3306` is the default listening port for MySQL server, and `mydb` is the name of the database you want to use.

Comment: Thanks Gord, its a typo here i was using jdbc inplace of http, but now the problem has solved don't know how but i cleaned and restart the eclipse